# Need Suggestion for settingup AD server on azure cloud with out having onprime AD server

Tags: active-directory, azure, entra-id

We are planning to setup AD server for our startup organization.

We are planning to create it on Azure Virtual Machines and we don't want to maintain any on premise AD server .

So my question is -is it possible to add all my client machines to my AD domain directly once I create AD server on one of my Azure VM.

our goal what ever the devices we connect from our office they should be in our office network

or is there any additional things do we need to configure to achieve this

Please provide more suggestions on this

Answer (score 2):

This depends a bit on your scenario - I would have to know more about it. You have few choices here:
1. Establish your Azure AD tenant and join your machines directly to Azure AD

This is not the same as on-prem AD join but depends on your requirements should do the job. My company is operating in this way (60+ people, consulting).

2. Create VM with standard AD but in Azure IaaS and establish a VPN between your network and Azure.  This will give you full AD, networking will be required.
3. If you need AD for servers but you don't want to establish full blown AD as VM:
   a/ Establish Azure AD and join your machines tehre
   b/ Enable Azure AD Domain Services - this will give you ability to run IaaS within AD network (some restrictions apply)

I had to remove a links because of my first post here but you can easily look it up :)

Comment: This is the correct answer, but bear in mind that option 2, AAD DS has some fairly significant limitations.

Comment: Yes, as I wrote - some restrictions apply. We have standard products which are running there in AAD DS environment like SQL, reporting services etc. and it works. It is designed for lift & shift scenarios. Depends what are exact requirements it might work or be too limited.

Comment: +1, if you want to deploy a AD in Azure VM, you should setup VPN to join domian.

Comment: Thank you all for the information on this.. I Appreciate all your efforts for guiding me on this...